# django leaflet custom popups

Tags: python, leaflet, popup, geodjango, django

I use some django project with PostGIS for database and leaflet map.
I have add simple leaflet popups like this :

[image: example]

and here the snippet code to call popups :

```
onEachFeature:function (feature,layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.kalcode.toString())

}
```

but because I want to show more details from my fields I want to add one more html popups left down of map  popups like this image :

[image: example 2]

Any idea what change I need about this tasks ?

Comment: This is more of a stackoverflow type question imo, may also be good to post a reproducible example using https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @GISKid i think is easy think but i stack now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you want to put a div there, then using HTML create a table, Then with the layer.on('click') event populate the layer with the feature attributes.

```
 <div class="sidebar">
    <h3 style="text-align:center;">Bird Map</h3>
    <table>
      <tr>
      <th align="left">Common Name</th>
      <td id='f1'></td></tr>  <tr>
      <th align="left">Location ID</th>
      <td id='f2'></td> 
      </tr> 
    </table>
  </div> 

layer.on('click', function (e) {
    var field1=document.getElementById('f1');
    field1.innerHTML=e.target.feature.properties.COMMON_NAM;
    var field2=document.getElementById('f2');
    field2.innerHTML=e.target.feature.properties.LOCALITY_I;
```

Comment: thank you for helpe me i try to follow your details but in  f1 don't show me somethink any idea why ? here the code :        `onEachFeature:function (feature,layer) {
              var field1=document.getElementById('f1');
             field1.innerHTML=e.target.feature.properties.toString();
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.kalcode.toString())

        }
        });`

Comment: My table has an id tag, the first cell it writes to is called f1, In the onEachFunction, I setup a layer.on click function an inside that I grab the values and using a document.getElementById('f1') I send the value to the f1 cell.   Here is an example using a div side panel. http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/baseball/Baseball.html 
 The two lines in the JavaScript can be shortened to document.getElementById('f1').innerHTML=e.target.feature.properties.kalcode.toString();  That might help.

Comment: can i download this code from Baseball.html  ?

Comment: Sure right click on it view source. Copy/paste to a text file, save as html. For the data go to http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/baseball/BaseBallFinal.json   and copy paste to a text file, save as BaseBallFinal.json. Place both in your web folder and it should work.

Comment: that i need is a very nice example thank you now i need to add my project

Comment: i find solution you are correct is very useful thank you